# Component breaks styles in Angular

Tags: angular, slider, bootstrap-5

I am newbie to Angular and I am working on my previous project to convert from .net to angular

But this question is completely related to Angular and excuse me if its a silly one.

I am trying to navigate between two pages(Components) and my styles are breaking

Styles in the sense I have a bootstrap slider which I have on my convertImageComponent

Now when I'm trying to Navigate from my homeComponent to convertImageComponent the slider is showing as Input and When I refresh the page then the slider shows perfectly.

Can anyone let me know where I went wrong or what is the right process to handle this.

Not only this but for every jquery plugin I have the same Issue.

Below is my code:

I have added the styles and scripts as shown in angular.json file

```
"styles": [
"src/assets/css/progressive-image.css",
"src/assets/css/bootstrap-slider.css"
],
"scripts": [
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
"src/assets/js/progressive-image.min.js",
"src/assets/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js"
]
```

home.component.html

```
 <a routerLink="/convertImage">
    <img src="../../assets/img/loading.png?tr=h-1,w-1:w-512,h-512" width="512" height="512"
    data-src="../../assets/img/apps/app1.png?tr=w-512,h-512"
    class="preview img-fluid lazy mx-auto d-block" alt="" />
    <h3 class="appname">App1<i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></h3>
 </a>
```

convertImage.component.html

```
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-3">
     <h5>Image Quality :</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xl-6">
    <input id="imgQuality" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text"
    name="imgQualitySlider" data-provide="slider"
    data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1"
    data-slider-value="50" data-slider-tooltip="always">
    </div>
</div>
```

homecomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

convertImagecomponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-convertImage',
  templateUrl: './convertImage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./convertImage.component.css']
})
export class convertImageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

This is my app-routing.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { convertImageComponent } from './convertImage/convertImage.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path:'home', component:HomeComponent },
  {path :'convertImage', component:convertImageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

What I have tried:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

And this didn't work

```
{path :'convertImage', component:convertImageComponent , runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' }
```

Output :

Before when first time routed to convertImage Component

[image]

After manually refreshing whole page

[image]

Comment: Requesting you to please create a minimal reproducible example to troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: haha:) Is this a big project..I have a simple anchor tag on homecomponent and using a simple routerLink to route to another component where the styles are not applying..When I reload the convertImageComponent the styles are re-applying..Thats it

Comment: If its not then what is the problem in create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Where do you want me to create when provided a fully working sample with code ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/ or https://codesandbox.io/ See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VimalPatel - Here is the demo https://cmosd.csb.app/superheroes

Answer (score 0):

I think you might run into a race condition.
Assume that once you refresh the page the entire JavaScript is already in the browsers cache and so the time between executing each of the loaded scripts is shorther.  The slider to render is then already/earlier present and it comes to "self resolved" slider registration by plugin itself.
The result then is what you expect initially.

To prevent this initially non renderng behavior you shoud take responsibility for rendering by yourself. So I would recommend to register the slider once you know sureley the slider element has been rendered.

```js
// You need to import jQuery here as well
import * as $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js';


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-convertImage',
  templateUrl: './convertImage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./convertImage.component.css']
})
export class convertImageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  private slider:any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit():void {
   // You're loading jQuery with bootstrap so this way is suitable
   // Natively I would recommend template vars (#imgQuality) and 
   // @ViewChild()decorator
   this.slider = $('#imgQuality').slider({});  
  }
}
```

Comment: I have initialized jquery in scripts as shown above and I have many components and everytime I need to initialize jquey and I think it's not a good idea the jquery slider is being called from another script which I have added to scripts array.

Comment: @coder Yeah ok then it's exactly the problem. That script from scripts array is executed before the according view has been rendered. So there's noting in DOM at that time slider can be applied to